# android emulator virtual scene upside down

Tags: android, android-emulator

So android emulator virtual scene is upside down and it looks like it meters as I test OCR recognition of some SDK and cannot get results.. Or maybe its not like that I have to find out, but anyway how can I fix this upside down or maybe its even mirrored ? Because also when I move there, controls works totally like if everything is mirrored for some reason. I tried playing with emulator settings and I tested API 21 and 23 emulators as they run also at usable speed, both with google api, x86 images.